# column contains null values

Tags: django, postgresql, constraints, sql-null

I added Person as a foreign key to the CareerHistory table.

```
    person = models.ForeignKey(
    Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None, related_name='careerist')
```

I set default=None thinking this would avoid that error when running migrations about making a new field on an existing table without a default value. However, instead I got

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "person_id" contains null values
```

Now, there are only 114 Persons in that table, and *all* of them have ids, so I find this error very confusing. I looked at this answer:
[SQL Django Null Constraint Error - cannot resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299563/sql-django-null-constraint-error-cannot-resolve)

and decided to try:

```
            person = models.ForeignKey(
    Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='', related_name='careerist')
```

However, this *still* came back with the *same* error.
Then I went to:

```
            person = models.ForeignKey(
    Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='', null=True, related_name='careerist')
```

But I *still* get the same error. I don't understand what is happening here. Can someone please explain, and show me how to fix this? I don't want to *just* fix it, I want to understand what is happening here. Maybe I need to edit my migrations file(s)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your adding the field, but without allowing `null`. By adding `null=True` you should resolve the issue during the migration.

```py
person = models.ForeignKey(
    Person, 
    on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
    null=True,
    default=None, 
    related_name='careerist'
)
```

> there are 114 Persons in that table, and all of them have ids, so I find this error very confusing

So when you add this column, the database doesn't know which career belongs to which person. So you have to implement a database migration to connect these two.

After the datamigration it's possible to remove the `null=True, default=None`.